# How to make the opened window must close at first before back to the main?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I want to make that second window must close first like alert dialog.
what should I add to this code when Button clicked:

```
Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/sec_win.fxml"));
Stage stage = new Stage();
Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a property called stage.initOwner(Stage stg) that allows this to happen.

Example:

```
public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
   Button jb = new Button("Click");
   jb.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler() {
        @Override
           public void handle(Event event) {
               makeAnotherStage(stage);
           }
       });

       GridPane gp = new GridPane();
       gp.getChildren().add(jb);
       Scene s = new Scene(gp);

       stage.setScene(s);
       stage.show();

    }

    private void makeAnotherStage(Stage st){
        Stage s = new Stage();

        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        Label l = new Label("Second Stage");
        gp.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene sc = new Scene(gp);

        s.initOwner(st);                        <------- initOwner
        s.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);  <------- Modality property

        s.setScene(sc);
        s.requestFocus();
        s.show();
    }
}
```

Oracle Documentation on Modality: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html